# How to close Popper context menu when selecting a menu item?

Tags: vue.js, popper

Can't find a way to close context menu upon picking an item, using [Popper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-popperjs). Seems like a fundamental feature though, am I missing something?

The only thing I see is a "hide" event but it's an event not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
<popper
  ref="popper"
  ...
>
   ...
</popper>
```

Then: `this.$refs.popper.doClose()`